# How to optimize my codes to make it faster and more user friendly?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, localhost

```
<div id="database"> 
<form action="http://localhost/database/edit.php"  method="post">
<br>Please enter the ID of item you want to edit: <input type="text" name="ID" /><br><br>
What do you want to change:<br> <br>
<input type="radio"  name="change" value="Name"/>Name<br><br>
<input type="radio"  name="change" value="Cause" size="100" />Cause <br><br>
<input type="radio"  name="change" value="Symptom" size="200" />Symptom <br><br>
<input type="radio"  name="change" value="Gene_affected" size="200" />Gene_affected <br><br>
   Change it to: <input type="text" name="New" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="clicked(event)" />
</form>
</div>
```

That is my `databse.php`

```
   <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET $_POST[change] = '$_POST[New]'
WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'");
echo "Change Successful<br>" ;
header("Location: databse.php");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

That is my `edit.php`

How can I change all my boxes in the table using 1 query?
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<div id="database"> 
<form action="http://localhost/database/edit.php"  method="post">
<br>Please enter the ID of item you want to edit: <input type="text" name="ID" /><br><br>
What do you want to change:<br> <br>
   Change Name to: <input type="text" name="New" /><br><br>
   Change Cause to: <input type="text" name="New1" /><br><br>
   Change Symptom to: <input type="text" name="New2" /><br><br>
   Change Gene_affected to: <input type="text" name="New3" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="clicked(event)" />
</form>
</div>
```

this is my new main php file. I manage to make it update all 4 boxes at once but its still so unreliable and slow. Help please?

```
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Name= '$_POST[New]' WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'");
mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Cause= '$_POST[New1]' WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'");
mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Symptom= '$_POST[New2]' WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'");
mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET Gene_affected= '$_POST[New3]' WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'");
 echo "Change Successful<br>" ;
 header("Location: databse.php");
 mysql_close($con);
```

Any suggestions to help me improve my codes? Thank you!

Comment: mysql_ is depreceted, consider using mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I updated my answer with a specific solution for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_` functions are deprecated, you should consider to use `msqli_` or pdo

Here's how to update multiple fields with `mysqli_`

```
$conn = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE pleasework SET 
   field1 = ?,  
   field2 = ?  
   WHERE ID = ?");
$conn->bind_param(
   $_POST['value1'],
   $_POST['value2'],
   $_POST['id']);
$conn->execute(); 
$conn->close();
```

---

Now that you're aware that `mysql_` is deprecated, here's the solution you were looking for:

```
$sql = "UPDATE pleasework SET column_name1='value', column_name2='value' WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a checkbox instead of radio inputs? For example:

Then on PHP side you would have this query:

```
$change_fields = array('Name', 'Cause', 'Symptom', 'Gene_affected');
$query = '';
foreach(change_fields as $field) {
    if(isset($_POST[field])) {
        $query .= ",$_POST[field] = '$_POST[New]'";
    }
}
$query = rtrim(query, ',');

if(!empty($query)) {
     mysql_query("UPDATE pleasework SET $query WHERE ID=$_POST[ID]");")
}
```

Normally I would excape these values and use some kind of wrapper database class, but that's something you want to do after you're comfortable with this.